# Restart program upon close while not using windows explorer

Tags: shell, google-chrome, batch-file, explorer, kiosk

I am running a "kiosk" by setting chrome as the shell for this specific user. This means explorer is not running during the session and only chrome.exe is open.

I can't use the official kiosk/custom shell because I don't have Windows enterprise/education.

I wrote a batch file which reopens chrome anytime it is closed, but it will not run from the startup folder, presumably because it relies on explorer.exe running.

```
# If chrome is not open, open it.

:LOOP
# Find tasks with "chrome.exe" as the name, write output to text file

tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" > c:\temp\tasks.txt

# If "No tasks" exists in text file, chrome is not running

findstr /I "No tasks" "c:\temp\tasks.txt"

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    TIMEOUT 5
)

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    TIMEOUT 10
)

GOTO :LOOP
```

As soon as I start explorer.exe, my batch file will start running and function correctly, but it won't run while otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Task scheduler does not require explorer.exe whereas startup applications do.